# Track reputation breakdown in Leagues for users with reputations under 200

Tags: feature-request, reputation-leagues

The [Stack Overflow Leagues page](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow) displays the count of users per reputation segment. Recent snapshot (with percentages added for perspective):

```
Total Rep      Users  Portion
---------  ---------  -------
100,000+         397    0.01%  
50,000+         1204    0.02%
25,000+         3287    0.05%
10,000+        10085    0.17%
5,000+         22176    0.37%
3,000+         37928    0.63%
2,000+         56428    0.94%
1,000+        104678    1.75%
500+          184194    3.08%
200+          311747    5.21%
1+           5987285
```

The breakdown stops at 200 rep, below which the vast majority (95%) of our users lie. There's even a footnote:

> users with less than 200 reputation are not tracked in the leagues

#### Show more granularity for the masses!

**Suggestion: Add segments for 100, 50 and 15.**

The thresholds of 50 and 15 are noteworthy, because they bestow the privileges of [commenting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) and [up-voting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) respectively, which in my experience are the most talked about, sought after and problematic privileges. Adding 100 is an obvious logarithmic step between 200 and 50.

Here's the result of [a query that includes those segments](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/535639/count-of-users-by-total-reputation-segment-more-granular-than-leagues):

```
Total Rep      Users  Portion
---------  ---------  -------
100,000+         397    0.01%  
50,000+         1204    0.02%
25,000+         3287    0.05%
10,000+        10085    0.17%
5,000+         22176    0.37%
3,000+         37928    0.63%
2,000+         56428    0.94%
1,000+        104678    1.75%
500+          184194    3.08%
200+          311747    5.21%
100+          494425    8.25%  <-- new segment
50+           716959   11.97%  <-- new segment (comment privilege)
15+          1313555   21.94%  <-- new segment (up-vote privilege)
1+           5987285
```

Graphing these numbers shows a smooth curve across the entire dataset, as shown by this [log version of the above query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/535639/graphable-log-version-of-count-of-users-by-total-reputation-segment-more-granu#graph):

[image: logarithmic graph]

so it's not as if the numbers get strange at lower reputation levels.

Is there a compelling reason there is not finer granularity?
Disk is cheap. CPU is cheap. Why not do it?

Comment: I expect this hasn't been done yet because the bucketing comes as a side-effect of the user-by-user stats, which *would* be rather more expensive to compute below 200 rep. Still, DRY aside, this shouldn't be especially difficult to implement.